# How do I turn off the Accessibility Inspector in the iOS 9 simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, accessibility, xcode-ui-testing, kif, kif-framework

The accessibility inspector is turned on by my KIF tests (apparently it's necessary for KIF to work.) Problem is, its window occludes controls some subsequent UI tests need to tap on and those tests fail.

How can I turn the Accessibility Inspector off when my KIF tests are done with it so my UI Tests can run?

*(Turning it off "manually" from the simulator's Settings app is not a solution—I'm looking for something I can call from code, set in the target or...?)*

Answer (score 1):

It is not on by default.  You must turn it on manually.

Comment: You're right. It's my KIF tests turning it on, and not turning it off—see edits above.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the following on [Stew Gleadow's blog](http://www.stewgleadow.com/blog/2011/11/16/enabling-accessibility-programatically-on-ios-devices/).

You just need to change the line:

```
CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("ApplicationAccessibilityEnabled"), kCFBooleanFalse, accessibilityDomain, kCFPreferencesAnyUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost);
```

change `kCFBooleanTrue` to `kCFBooleanFalse`.

```
+ (void)_enableAccessibilityInSimulator {
    NSAutoreleasePool *autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *appSupportLocation = @"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport";

    NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
    NSString *simulatorRoot = [environment objectForKey:@"IPHONE_SIMULATOR_ROOT"];
    if (simulatorRoot) {
        appSupportLocation = [simulatorRoot stringByAppendingString:appSupportLocation];
    }

    void *appSupportLibrary = dlopen([appSupportLocation fileSystemRepresentation], RTLD_LAZY);

    CFStringRef (*copySharedResourcesPreferencesDomainForDomain)(CFStringRef domain) = dlsym(appSupportLibrary, "CPCopySharedResourcesPreferencesDomainForDomain");

    if (copySharedResourcesPreferencesDomainForDomain) {
        CFStringRef accessibilityDomain = copySharedResourcesPreferencesDomainForDomain(CFSTR("com.apple.Accessibility"));

        if (accessibilityDomain) {
            CFPreferencesSetValue(CFSTR("ApplicationAccessibilityEnabled"), kCFBooleanFalse, accessibilityDomain, kCFPreferencesAnyUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost);
            CFRelease(accessibilityDomain);
        }
    }

    [autoreleasePool drain];
}
```